# How to extract specific substring from a bigger string java

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have the following string:

```
String n = "(.........)(......)(.......)(......) etc"
```

I want to write a method which will fill a `List<String>` with every substring of `n` which is between `(` and `)` .  Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Can the brackets be nested?

Comment: This is the kind of fun thing that you'd challenge yourself to do, not get other people to do it for you!

Comment: no there arent any nested brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done in one line:

```
String[] parts = input.replaceAll("(^.*\\()|(\\).*$)", "").split("\\)\\(");
```

The call to `replaceAll()` strips off the leasing and trailing brackets (plus any other junk characters before/after those first/last brackets), then you just `split()` on bracket pairs.

Comment: Clever... assuming the input is well-formed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with the String methods, so I'm sure there's a way that it could be done without having to code it yourself, and just using some fancy method, but here you go:

Tested, works 100% perfect :)

```
String string = "(stack)(over)(flow)";
ArrayList<String> subStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int c = 0; c < string.length(); c++) {
    if(string.charAt(c) == '(') {
        c++;
        String newString = "";
        for(;c < string.length() && string.charAt(c) != ')'; c++) {
            newString += string.charAt(c);
        }
        subStrings.add(newString);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will work, but since it doesn't handle nested brackets, I see no advantage over a simple regular expression (which can't handle nested brackets either). `newString += string.charAt(c);` is not very efficient, you could use a `StringBuilder` to improve performance.

Comment: @jlordo I guess he'll have to build on that himself. (Haha).

Answer (score 1):

If the (...) pairs aren't nested, you can use a regular expression in Java. Take a look at the java.util.regex.Pattern class.

Answer (score 1):

I made this regex version, but it's kind of lengthy.  I'm sure it could be improved upon.  (note: "n" is your input string)

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(n);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        list.add(matcher.group(1));  // 1 == stuff between the ()'s
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to keep track of the next-match offset and plug it in with the `find(int)` method; the no-arg `find()` method handles all that for you.

Comment: hey, you're right!  thanks Alan!  I updated the code accordingly to remove the `int offset` counter from the find() call and its incrementation in the loop (is that a word?).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    String in = "(bla)(die)(foo)";
    in = in .substring(1,in.length()-1);
    String[] out = in .split(Pattern.quote(")("));
```